# Complex integral with exponent functions.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let $w(t)=a\frac{\sin(t)}{1-\cos(t)}$
and $a, b$ be some complex numbers different from $0,-1, 1$.

> Calculate $$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{i(t-w(t))}-e^{-iw(t)}}{e^{it}-b}dt$$

I guess that it is possible since the denominator is never zero, and the numerator is a product of $e^{it}-1$ and $e^{-w(x)}$, so the poles are removed.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$w(t)=a\frac{\sin(t)}{1-\cos(t)}=a \cot \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)$$
Let 
$$a \cot \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)=x \implies x=2 \cot ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\implies dt=-\frac{2 a}{a^2+x^2}\,dx$$
$$\int\frac{e^{i(t-w(t))}-e^{-iw(t)}}{e^{it}-b}\,dt=-\int\frac{4 a^2 e^{-i x}}{\left(a^2+x^2\right) (a (b+1)+i (b-1) x)}\,dx$$ Now, using partial fraction decomposition
$$-\frac{4 a^2 }{\left(a^2+x^2\right) (a (b+1)+i (b-1) x)}=$$ $$\frac{i}{x-i a}-\frac{i}{b (x+i a)}+\frac{(b-1)^2}{a b (b+1)+i (b-1) b x}$$ making that we face three itegrals looking like
$$\int\frac{e^{-ix}}{c+ dx}=\frac{e^{\frac{i c}{d}} }{d}\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{i (c+d x)}{d}\right)$$ In terms of $x$, the antiderivative is "just"
$$\frac{i e^{-a} \left(e^{2 a} b \text{Ei}(-a-i x)-(b-1) e^{\frac{2 a b}{b-1}}
   \text{Ei}\left(-\frac{a (b+1)}{b-1}-i x\right)-\text{Ei}(a-i x)\right)}{b}$$

Comment: But how did you get the third line? Why my integral is equal to integral of $-\frac{4a^{2}e^{-ix}}{(a^2+x^2)(a(b+1)+i(b-1)x)}$? I am only able to see why there is a factor $-\frac{2}{a^{2}+x^{2}}$. The rest seems mysterious. Did you use there integration by parts?